# How to pass data from Pure native android class to javascript

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a simple demo where react native prints "Hello world". I am loading react native into my fragment. I want to pass this message from native code, so I am passing initial properties in `startReactApplication`. But it is displaying empty. Is anything is missing. I am new to react native. Thanks in advance.

```
public abstract class ReactFragment extends Fragment {
private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

// This method returns the name of our top-level component to show
public abstract String getMainComponentName();

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(context);
    mReactInstanceManager =
            ((MainApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
                    .getReactNativeHost()
                    .getReactInstanceManager();

}

@Override
public ReactRootView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    return mReactRootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Create reactRootView and reactInstanceManager as described in the demo app
    Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
    initialProps.putString("message", "Hello World");

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(
            mReactInstanceManager,
            getMainComponentName(),
            initialProps
    );

    //to pass initial properties
    /*mReactRootView.startReactApplication(
            mReactInstanceManager,
            getMainComponentName(),
            initialProps
    );*/
}}


public class HelloFragment extends ReactFragment {
@Override
public String getMainComponentName() {
    return "MyReactNativeApp"; // name of our React Native component we've registered
}}
```

React native code (index.js):

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {render() {
return (
  /*<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.hello}>Hello, World from React Native</Text>
  </View>*/
  <View>
  <Text>{this.props.message}</Text></View>
  );
  ToastExample.show('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT)
  }
  }

  var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: "center"
   },
   hello: {
   fontSize: 20,
   textAlign: "center",
   margin: 10
   }
   });

   AppRegistry.registerComponent("MyReactNativeApp", () => HelloWorld);
```

Answer (score 0):

In version > 0.59 you should override ReactActivityDelegate in MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "App";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Bundle props = new Bundle();
                props.putString("message", "Hello World");

                return props;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

}
```

if you want more data in differents components not only in the root you should use https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: But I want to send the data only while loading react into my fragment.